# Dynamically spacing text on a global map python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cartopy

I have a map of city locations across the globe and want to plot the city name next to each dot. I have a dataframe that contains the city name, as well as the latitude and longitude of each city, and some additional information.

```
Rank    Name    Pop_2019    Pop_2018    Change  latitude    longitude   TC Risk
0   1   Tokyo   37393129    37435191    -0.0011 35.682839   139.759455  1.0
1   2   Delhi   30290936    29399141    0.0303  28.651718   77.221939   0.0
2   3   Shanghai    27058479    26317104    0.0282  31.232276   121.469207  1.0
3   4   Sao Paulo   22043028    21846507    0.0090  -23.550651  -46.633382  0.0
4   5   Mexico City 21782378    21671908    0.0051  19.432630   -99.133178  0.0
```

I take this info, and run a small script that creates a map, plots a black dot at the lon,lat point and then adds the text of the name.

```
ax1 = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax1.stock_img()
x = data.loc[data['TC Risk'] == 1, 'longitude']
y = data.loc[data['TC Risk'] == 1, 'latitude']
names=data.loc[data['TC Risk'] == 1, 'Name']
ax1.scatter(x,y, s=3, c='k', transform=ccrs.Geodetic())

xy=list(zip(x, y))
for (x,y), label in zip(xy, names):  
    ax1.text(x, y, label, ha='center', size=10, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())    
plt.show()
```

However, some cities are very close to each other, for example in China, and it is impossible to read the names. Also the text plots on top of the dot. I would love some lines of code that dynamically space out the text so that they are readable, yet still indicate which dot they belong to. Any ideas on how I would go about this? I'll attach a picture of the map for reference.
[image: Global map]

Comment: place a point on the city, draw line to name, space names out using a method that ensures the lines don't cross each other (radial symmetry?)

Comment: Yes, that's a good idea but I don't know how to do that. Otherwise I would have already done that! :)